# select where.... electrical status is required in ms sql 2005

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table planning sheet as follows

```
SONo.         LineNo.         ElectricalStatus  
1              10              Required  
1              20              Required  
2              10              NotRequired  
2              20              Required  
2              30              Required  
3              10              NotRequired  
4              10              NotRequired
```

I want to display all records + beside the SONo., say if electrical status is required or not.

e.g.,

```
SONo.         ElectricalStatus  
1             Required  
2             Required
```

because SONo. 3 and 4 have no records with electrical status as required and SONo. 2 has records with electrical status required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SONO,  ElectricalStatus
FROM tablename
WHERE  ElectricalStatus = 'Required';
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d3eb/1)

this will give you:

```
| SONO | ELECTRICALSTATUS |
---------------------------
|    1 |         Required |
|    2 |         Required |
```